format EFI, Recovery partitions windows 10 in clean install?
I'm going to do a clean install of Windows, but during the installation I want to format all the partitions and then delete them, but I have some concerns!
As you can see in the picture below, I have 5 drivers, three of which seem to be vital and important (EFI system partition and the other two are recovery partitions. The partition that is related to recovery and has a volume of 900 megabytes is related to WinRE tools, and the other recovery partition that is 21 gigabytes is related to BIOS_RVY.).
If I delete them, will there be any problem? Will they be created automatically after installing Windows? Because it seems that these three drives are stored in the hard disk by the laptop manufacturer.
My laptop is MSI gf65 thin 10sdr. Do you think I should delete them or not?


How are you performing the clean install? Are you using the option to reset inside windows, using the manufacturer installation media or media from Microsoft (media creation tool)

Removing all partitions and reinstalling using either manufacturer provided, or downloaded Microsoft media should work fine. The recovery partition won't be recreated by the Microsoft media, and probably will with manufacturer media.
I've never used the recovery partition, most of the drivers are not up-to-date and usually available to download from the manufacturer if windows update fails to locate them for you automatically. Bundled software is the same, most you probably don't want and there are newer versions of the ones you do online.
If you have a spare SSD (or new one) then swapping out the old one lets you have a fallback should something not work.
